# Use stargazer(..., order = c(...)) for as.factor(var)

Tags: r, stargazer

I have a regression model like this:

```
Call:
glm(formula = DV ~ as.factor(IV), family = "binomial", data = df)

[...]
Coefficients:
                                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                          -2.104e+01  3.956e+03  -0.005   0.9958    
as.factor(IV)AAA                      2.626e-01  2.962e-01   0.887   0.3752    
as.factor(IV)BBB                      4.150e-01  3.176e-01   1.307   0.1913    
as.factor(IV)CCC                      8.060e-01  3.551e-01   2.270   0.0232 *  
as.factor(IV)DDD                      2.640e+00  3.210e-01   8.222  < 2e-16 ***
```

Using `stargazer`, I would like to reorder the output. I want to change the *order of entries* to `"as.factor(IV)BBB", "as.factor(IV)AAA", "as.factor(IV)DDD", "as.factor(IV)CCC"` and rename them to `c("BBB", "AAA", "DDD", "CCC")`; I have tried with this and similar calls:

```
stargazer(model, type = "html", out = "./out/test.html", 
      title = "Title", order = c("as.factor(IV)BBB", "as.factor(IV)AAA",
                                 "as.factor(IV)DDD", "as.factor(IV)CCC")
```

Unfortunately, I can neither get it to work nor find help in the documentation.

Comment: I think you need to use the numeric index rather than the name, e.g `order = c(2, 1, 4, 3)` to change the order and rename with `covariate.labels`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the numeric indexes to change the order and then rename using `covariate.labels`

```
stargazer(model, type = "html", out = "./out/test.html", 
      title = "Title", order = c(2, 1, 4, 3), covariate.labels = c("BBB", "AAA", "DDD", "CCC"))
```